# Cannot connect R to DB2

Tags: r, jdbc, db2

I want to connect `R 3.2.3` to `DB2`. I tried this code :

```
library(RJDBC)
jcc = JDBC("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver","c:/installed/sqllib/java/db2jcc4.jar")
```

I get this error :

```
Error: could not find function "JDBC"
```

Any Ideas ?

Comment: I would say there is no function JDBC ? did you try help(JDBC) to check?

Comment: you installed **install.packages("RJDBC",dep=TRUE)**, right?

Comment: I installed it normally `install.packages("RJDBC")` is that mandatory ?
@timat I followed the instructions from this website :https://www.r-bloggers.com/connecting-to-a-db2-database-from-r/

Comment: from the website your cite: "You also need to install the RJDBC package.". How did you install the package ?

Comment: I installed it using the command line `install.packages("RJDBC")`

Comment: it works on my install, so either you've made a spelling error, either you should update R..

Comment: When you execute just `library(RJDBC)` does that give you an error?

Comment: @dan1111 no it loads the library normally...

Comment: Note: while this doesn't solve the immediate problem, we regularly use the RODBC package to connect to DB2.  That may be an alternative if this proves difficult to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Tantaoui, I suggest you take a look at ibmdbR, which is a dedicated R data frame API to DB2 and dashDB data: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ibmdbR/ibmdbR.pdf