# Is it possible to connect to SAS Data Warehouse (DB2) using R?

Tags: r, sas, db2, odbc, data-warehouse

Currently, using SAS Enterprise Guide, we have some code that pulls data from a data warehouse that has a seemingly straightforward 'CONNECT TO DB2(x,y,z,)' statement in a PROC SQL where x=database name, y=user ID, z=password.

Looking in Tools > Connections > Profiles, I can find the host name and port for the connection. I'm trying to see if there's a way to use this information (and find any other needed information) to connect to the same data warehouse using R. Other posts here on SO have some code using JDBC or RODBC, but I wasn't able to get anywhere with that, as they mention drivers (which I don't know anything about) and the Oracle folder in my C drive didn't seem to have any of that information.

After reaching out to someone involved with the warehouse, their response was "it is a SAS data warehouse and not accessible via direct ODBC connections."

I'm not too sure what other information to ask for or provide for this, but do any of you know if what I'm looking to do is possible? Are SAS Data Warehouses structured some way that would prevent me from accessing it in R? If I can, what else do I need besides the host name, port, database name, user ID, and password?

Thanks in advance, I'm pretty new to all of this

Comment: [Possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40525630/cannot-connect-r-to-db2) [duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46202334/how-to-connect-db2-from-r)

Comment: If it's in DB2, R should be able to access it via RJDBC. I'm unsure of what a SAS Data Warehouse is in DB2. My idea of a SAS Data Warehouse is a group of .sas7bdat files which R can definitely read, which makes a SAS Data Warehouse in DB2 seem paradoxical...

Comment: Sounds more like the business policy is that you are not allowed to access it that way.  Not that it is impossible.